# PHP Script Stops Working After Upgrading Hosts

Tags: curl, cpanel, yahoo, finance

I have a stock script thay uses yahoo finance, which has worked fine for ages,

I upgraded to cpanel and now the script does not work.

I have called Godaddy 2 times and they cannot help me.

This simple bit of code will work on my old server but not my new one, ($curl is enabled)

```
<?php
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/dnh?s=goog&n=5&e=.csv");
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$data=ob_get_clean();
$data=explode(",",$data);
$data=str_replace('"','',$data);
foreach ($data as $results)
echo "<td>$results</td>";
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide more detail on "does not work". What is the expected and actual behavior and are there any error messages?

Comment: Look in your logs, as well, not just the browser/output.

Comment: my script is to get stok information, however the above code is just a small test script for the basics, will just output 1 long line of text

no error logs - same php version - same host

Comment: same script on both servers
[link](http://hdpixeldesign.com/news-feed3.php)
[link](http://hdpixelprint.co.uk/news-feed3.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is not your fault, since the last couple of days there is a hitch in Yahoo's service.

Interestingly, if you use the http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=DATA&f=n0s0l1c6o0m7j4k0j0e7e8r5r0t8

Today it return with this:

```
N/A,N/A,94.78,N/A,N/A,3.07,19.84M,N/A,N/A,0.26,0.56,8.92,N/A,108.24
```

Two days ago it gave the following result:

```
Tableau Software,DATA,93.195,+1.155,92.11,+1.7776,19.8M,101.30,52.02,0.26,0.56,8.92,1150.50,108.24
```

Comment: Thank you, it has been sending me mad.

I am currently trying to scrape the data from there page instead but i am not having any luck.

All i need is the news section: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=goog+Headlines